# multiple flume twitter agents

Tags: twitter, hadoop, flume

im learning hadoop, flume etc and one of the projects I started was sentiment analysis, which is OK but now im trying to expand by collecting multiple sets of data, this is my flume.conf:

```
    TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
    TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
    TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS HDFS2
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = xxx
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = xxxx
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = xxx
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = xxxx
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = bbc
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://xxx:8020/user/flume/tweets/
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
    TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
    TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
    TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

what im hoping to achieve is put all tweets about bbc in the above location but also use the following config to put tweets about liverpool into a seperate folder:

```
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = liverpool
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS2.channel = MemChannel
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS2.type = hdfs
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS2.hdfs.path = hdfs://xxx:8020/user/flume/tweets/liverpool/
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS2.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS2.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS2.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS2.hdfs.rollSize = 0
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS2.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
    TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel2.type = memory
    TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel2.capacity = 10000
    TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel2.transactionCapacity = 10
```

This isnt working and I cant work out why, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the error you see? You might have already looked at this [blog post from cloudera](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/09/analyzing-twitter-data-with-hadoop)

Comment: normally i see only one agent running and all data going to one folder

Answer (score 0):

This answer is probably a bit late but I think it doesn't work because you can only have one open connection to the Twitter Streaming API using the same app.

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/14935

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/7542

> @kurrik Arne Roomann-Kurrik 
>   Which streaming endpoint are you using?
>
> For general streams, you should only make one connection from the same
>   IP. For userstreams, one or two connections from the same IP. For site
>   streams, multiple connections are supported (note that site streams is
>   still in limited beta).

Comment: Please post the pertinent part from the link in your answer, if the link becomes invalid or is moved, then this answer will no longer be helpful.